# WIF sliding expiration session vs refresh token

Tags: angularjs, oauth, session-cookies, access-token, wif

I implemented an WEB API 2.x with Windows Identity Foundation OAuth and Owin middleware. Problem is that expiration for the token is fixed. I have requirements that user can stay active (sliding expiration) of say 15 minutes.

I read that there is an implementation of sliding expiration using cookie and SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived. Is it an appropriate approach for Web api? How does this cookies expiration work with the OAuth/Owin token expiration time?

There is on the other hand, refresh token. For now, the application is not an iPad app where once logged in and stay in. It's more of a web browser app. The fact that the refresh token is such long live worries me; along with additional columns in implementing token refresh approach.

I am confused why people take such different approaches. Is the cookie approach more for MVC instead of WebAPI? I have my AngularJS app as front end. My implementation is what they called a two-legged Server-client Web api. Authentication and application is the same server.

This is the closest that I found http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/